# Subreports in Crystal Report XI

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, report

I have a doubt about the Subreports. As you know, when you run a Report in Visual Studio and there are Subreports, they may be selected and will open in another window.

What I have to do to unable that selection of the Subreports?

I use Visual Studio 2008 and Crystal Reports XI.

I hope I explained well and sorry for my English :P

Greetings,

ikermi89

Answer (score 0):

the only thing that i have found thus far that works is to put a text object on top of the sub report.This works if you know the size of your sub report and your sub report does not span over one page.